# Insert values into table from a range

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to do an insert to a table (say table1), where i want to insert a range of numbers after appending a char or int declare?

ex. 
for Range 1-10

```
abc1,
abc2,
abc3,
abc4,
.
.
.
```

any ideas?

Comment: What the hell is a range?  Where did it come from?

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fond of recursive CTEs for this purpose:

```
with nums as (
      select @rangestart as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from nums
      where n < @rangeend
     )
insert into table1(col)
    select 'abc' + cast(nums.n as varchar(255))
    from nums;
```

If you have more than 100 numbers, you should use the `MAXRECURSION` option.  Also, any numbers table can serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 4):

I like Gordon's answer better than mine but it didn't work for me because SQL Server only allows a limited amount of recursion (100 levels according to the error message).

So here's my solution using a while() loop:

```
Declare @Current int = 1
Declare @End int = 20
Declare @Strings as table(Text varchar(5))

WHILE @Current <= @End
BEGIN  
    Insert Into @Strings Values('abc' + Cast(@Current as varchar(2)))
    Set @Current = @Current + 1
END  

Select * From @Strings
```

Comment: Note: I discovered after I wrote this that it is possible to change SQL Server's recursion level.

Answer (score 3):

Gordon Linoff solution works great! Only did one minor modification.
For those looking for future solution.

```
DECLARE
    @rangestart INT,
    @rangeend INT
SET @rangestart = 1
SET @rangeend = 10
;
with nums as (
      select @rangestart as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from nums
      where n < @rangeend
     )
insert into Table1(Colum)
    select 'abc' + cast(nums.n as varchar(255))
    from nums;
```

In my test table, the artist column is my test table.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM16h.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
with nums as (
  select 1 as n
  union all
  select n + 1 as n
  from nums
  where n <= 9
 )
```

insert into table1(col)
    select 'abc' + cast(nums.n as varchar(255))
    from nums;

select * from table1